# Java: get data fast: store in memory vs read from file

Tags: java, performance, file-writing, bigdata

Iam writing a data table generator tool and have some performance problems - I need to care about RAM usage and time of generating. That is really a *key* in my program.

1) I **need** to store final data in a single **file** (one file = one table, to load it later when all files will be generated), like:

```
111|aaaa|bbba
112|aaab|bbbb
113|aaac|bbbc
114|aaad|bbbd...
```

I could have many columns and even milion of rows. All values are correct.

2) Now, I need to generate single value to the next table using values from one of previously genereted table. My program can also save single column into temporary file (to read it in future), like:

```
aaaa
aaab
aaac
aaad...
```

Now, the **main** problem is that I need to randomly 'read' new value even milion times, the same as row counter is.

How to do it effectively ? Which tools use ? I have two options:

- Store all 2nd column 'available values' from temporary file in some array / arraylist and use for eg. .get(int index) method and return value
- Read specific line from that file and return value

Thanks for help

Comment: An In-memory DB since you need to read randomly? Disk reads/writes are always slower than memory reads/writes...

Comment: I know that are slower, but I also need to care about RAM. Look at usage if I store milion of values in array / arraylist...

Comment: It's either speed, or low RAM usage. Pick one, not both. I am not going to recommend you a specific solution. I recommend that you try out different possible solutions, benchmark the hell out of them, with "realistic" data, and then make your decision. There is no "one size fits all" solution.

Comment: Why do you **need** to store tables in a file. Have you considered using an embedded db (e.g. H2) ?

Answer (score 2):

> How to do it effectively ?

To read a file randomly, you need to know the offset of each record. I would store this is a binary file with a 4 byte or 8 byte offset for the start of each line.

You can use a library like [Chronicle Map](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map) which allows you to random read any record in a file by a key.